# 'float' vs. 'double' precision

Tags: c, floating-point

The code

```
float x  = 3.141592653589793238;
double z = 3.141592653589793238;
printf("x=%f\n", x);
printf("z=%f\n", z);
printf("x=%20.18f\n", x);
printf("z=%20.18f\n", z);
```

will give you the output

```
x=3.141593
z=3.141593
x=3.141592741012573242
z=3.141592653589793116
```

where on the third line of output `741012573242` is garbage and on the fourth line `116` is garbage. Do doubles always have 16 significant figures while floats always have 7 significant figures? Why don't doubles have 14 significant figures?

Comment: A float has 23 bits of precision, and a double has 52.

Comment: Detail: [binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has a 53 bit significant (52 explicitly stored)  [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) has 24 bit (23 explicitly stored).

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Floating point numbers in C use [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) encoding.

This type of encoding uses a sign, a significand, and an exponent.

Because of this encoding, many numbers will have small changes to allow them to be stored.

Also, the number of significant digits can change slightly since it is a binary representation, not a decimal one.

Single precision (float) gives you 23 bits of significand, 8 bits of exponent, and 1 sign bit.

Double precision (double) gives you 52 bits of significand, 11 bits of exponent, and 1 sign bit.

Comment: Does the C standard enforce an encoding?

Comment: C99 does, previously it was up to the compiler.

Comment: gcc (and all others that I know of) use IEEE 754, it just wasn't specified until C99.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? I'm looking at the standard and it appears to be up to the implementer.

Comment: -1 This statement is blatantly false: "Because of this encoding, you can never guarantee that you will not have a change in your value."

Comment: @Alan: C99 does not require IEEE floating point; it just recommends it.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I can't find the reference for where I read that.  As for the 'blatantly false' part, I was simplifying to they would know that the number they put in won't necessarily be the number that gets stored.

Comment: @Alan: R.. is correct; Annex F (which specifies IEEE-754 bindings) is normative, but only in effect if an implementation defines `__STDC_IEC_559__`.  An implementation that does not define that macro is free not to conform to IEEE-754.

Comment: @Alan: Under IEEE 754, it's easily guaranteed that there is no change in the values `0.5`, `0.046875`, or `0.376739501953125` versus their decimal representations. (These are all diadic rationals with numerator fitting in the mantissa and base-2 logarithm of the denominator fitting in the exponent.)

Comment: Detail: [binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has a 53 bit significant (52 explicitly stored)  [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) has 24 bit (23 explicitly stored).

Comment: The 53 bits of `double`s give about 16 digits of precision. The 24 bits of `float`s give about 7 digits of precision.

Answer (score 45):

> Do doubles always have 16 significant
>   figures while floats always have 7
>   significant figures?

No.  Doubles always have 53 significant **bits** and floats always have 24 significant **bits** (except for denormals, infinities, and NaN values, but those are subjects for a different question).  These are binary formats, and you can only speak clearly about the precision of their representations in terms of binary digits (bits).

This is analogous to the question of how many digits can be stored in a binary integer: an unsigned 32 bit integer can store integers with up to 32 bits, which doesn't precisely map to any number of decimal digits: all integers of up to 9 decimal digits can be stored, but a lot of 10-digit numbers can be stored as well.

> Why don't doubles
>   have 14 significant figures?

The encoding of a double uses 64 bits (1 bit for the sign, 11 bits for the exponent, 52 explicit significant bits and one implicit bit), which is *double* the number of bits used to represent a float (32 bits).

Answer (score 11):

It's usually based on significant figures of both the exponent and significand in base 2, not base 10. From what I can tell in the C99 standard, however, there is no specified precision for floats and doubles (other than the fact that 1 and `1 + 1E-5` / `1 + 1E-7` are distinguishable [`float` and `double` repsectively]). However, the number of significant figures is left to the implementer (as well as which base they use internally, so in other words, an implementation could decide to make it based on 18 digits of precision in base 3). [1]

If you need to know these values, the constants `FLT_RADIX` and `FLT_MANT_DIG` (and `DBL_MANT_DIG` / `LDBL_MANT_DIG`) are defined in float.h.

The reason it's called a `double` is because the number of bytes used to store it is double the number of a float (but this includes both the exponent and significand). The IEEE 754 standard (used by most compilers) allocate relatively more bits for the significand than the exponent (23 to 9 for `float` vs. 52 to 12 for `double`), which is why the precision is more than doubled.

1: Section 5.2.4.2.2 ( http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf )

Comment: Typo?  C89 requires an epsilon of at most `1E-9` for `double`, not `1E-7`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly *double* precision because of how [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) works, and because binary doesn't really translate well to decimal. Take a look at the standard if you're interested.