# When CGPointMake meets big number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to make a time based drawing. For example: define a point for later use.

```
CGPoint testPoint = CGPointMake(2341.2345, 1350046324.1234);
```

Then testPoint.y becomes 1350046336.00 which is not we put there.
I am using Xcode 4.5.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGPoint uses float (32bit) datatypes (at least on iOS6).

From the headers:

```
CGPointMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y) ...
```

with

```
typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;
```

and

```
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
```

So this results in my test code:

```
CGPoint testPoint1 = CGPointMake(2341.2345, 1350046324.1234);
CGPoint testPoint2 = CGPointMake(2341.2345f, 1350046324.1234f);
double d = 1350046324.1234;
float f = 1350046324.1234;

NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f", testPoint1.y, testPoint2.y, d, f);
```

printing to the log:

```
1350046336.000000 1350046336.000000 1350046324.123400 1350046336.000000
```

So you just left the range of numbers where single precision floats are good enough. 
Thats all.

BTW.: I did think CGFloat is double before I stumbled upon your question.

Answer (score 2):

`CGPoint` is defined in `CGGeometry.h`:

```
struct CGPoint {
  CGFloat x;
  CGFloat y;
};
```

On 32-bit systems `CGFloat` is a `typedef` to `float`. iPhone/iPad is a 32-bit system. The last piece of information - `float` numbers in C  (Objective C is a strict superset of C):

> Floating point numbers in C use IEEE 754 encoding.
>   Because of this encoding, you can never guarantee that you will not
>   have a change in your value.

You can read the entire discussion here: [float vs. double precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision)

Answer (score 0):

If you write :

```
CGPoint testPoint = CGPointMake(2341.2345f, 1350046324.1234f);
```

Is it better ?

Comment: Putting an `f` on the end declares the constant as a (32-bit) float.