# Why does PHP transform 15+ digit long integer on output

Tags: php, integer

Why does `echo 100000000000000;` output `1.0E+14` and not `100000000000000`?

This kind of *transformation* of integers on output happens only for integers that are 15 digits long and longer.

Comment: To be fair, the other question's title isn't worded very nicely.

Comment: `echo number_format(100000000000000,0,null,'');`

Comment: @PHPNooB OP asks way more questions than provides answers, so the *rep* is from asking questions and as such I believe he would not know this as his profile does not indicate he is a PHP expert. Also, as Jimbo pointed out the title is indeed badly worded. Please do some research like clicking the profile, before you accuse the OP of badge whoring.

Comment: @Jimbo Doesn't really matter. The point of flagging duplicates is to redirect to answers and avoid duplication of efforts, not to nag at the OP for not searching enough. (That said, it's not exactly a duplicate because that question is about numbers that certainly can be represented as integers.)

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey, The question you link to, asks about floats, while my question asks about integers.

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey Although the core answer might be the same, the questions are approaching the problem from two different sides. And as you can see the answers in the other question are in a quite different direction.

Comment: yeah my bad, its very similar but not identical; agree with @HaralanDobrev that it is the same question and answer but coming from the opposite direction. and my apologies for accusing the OP of badge whoring ... that was inappropriate, and i never should have said that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PHP will convert an integer to float if it is bigger than PHP_INT_MAX. For 32-bit systems this is 2147483647.

The answer to the questions is related to the string representation of floats in PHP.

If the exponent in the [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) is bigger than `13` or smaller than `-4`, PHP will use scientific representation when printing floats.

Examples:

```
echo 0.0001; // 0.0001;

echo 0.00001; // 1.0E-5

// 14 digits
echo 10000000000000; // 10000000000000

// 15 digits
echo 100000000000000; // 1.0E+14
```

See [float vs. double precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision)

Answer (score 6):

That number is too big to fit into a 32 bit integer so PHP is storing it in a float.

See the integer overflow section in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

On the off chance that you need really big integers, look into [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).

Comment: What is the largest integer that would fit in 32 bit?

Comment: the max int 32 value is 2,147,483,647 (2.1E+9)

Comment: If this was the reason, then all numbers larger than PHP_INT_MAX would be represented in scientific notation. But this is not the case.

Comment: That is an excellent point. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

PHP cannot handle integers that big, and therefore treats them as floats. Floats are typically represented in scientific notation to take into account the inaccuracies past a certain number of significant digits.

Answer (score 2):

The number is too big to be stored as integer by PHP on your platform, 
so it is stored as a floating-point number. 
The rules of conversion to string are different for float-numbers and integers.

Try the following:

```
var_dump(100000000000000);
echo(is_int(100000000000000) ? 'an integer' : 'not an integer');
```

Output:

```
float(1.0E+14) 
not an integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Any number larger than PHP's built-in integer size is stored and represented as a float.

To format a number in a particular way on output, use a function such as `printf` .