# I met a trouble about float.Help me

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
float abc = 20130401.0f;
NSLog(@"abc = %f",abc);
```

result:

> 2013-04-08 15:47:38.963 CCLearnIphone[5034:c07]   abc =
>   20130400.000000

It's the same to use double.

How can I express an eight-digit number?

I know precision is lost but .000000 should not be 1.0000000.

%f should be 0.9xxxxx etc

why is it .000000 rounded to 1.000000?

Comment: how many digits you want after decimal point?

Comment: If you need greater precision use a `double`. You can see a similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision

Comment: use NSLog(@"abc = %.2f",abc); you get 20130400.00

Comment: @Alladinian It's the same to use double.How can I express an eight-digit number?

Answer (score 0):

your number is too hight  for a float var so you have to change it like double and remove the 'f' character at the end of your number

```
double abc = 20130401.0;
NSLog(@"abc = %f",abc);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's due to the precision of `float`: about 7 decimal digits.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5098949/104790

Answer (score -1):

> > why is it .000000 rounded to 1.000000?

That's not the case. 20130401 is rounded to 20130400 because 20130400 is the closest value that a `float` can represent.

Comment: why `float abc = 19999991`, prints to 19999992. Any Hard and fast rule, so that without computer we can tell the result?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Without calculating exponent and mantissa it's difficult to tell if a value is exactly representable in a floating point type. The simplest rule of thumb is: Less than 7 decimal digits.

Comment: Here's an IEEE 754 converter that shows binary and decimal representations of any entered number: http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/