# Adding Float Causes wrong answer

Tags: objective-c

I am adding two floats like:

```
NSString *val1=@"355.00";
NSString *val2=@"55555550.00";

NSString *result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[val1 floatValue]+[val2 floatValue]];
```

> The answer i am getting is **55555908.00** while on calculator it is
>   **55555905.00**

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like floating point precision problems to me

Comment: You can use `doubleValue` instead of `floatValue` to add some more precision, but beyond about 14 digits even doubles will show floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=053053053053053053053048

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, this is a floating point precision problem.
A `float` has a precision of about 7 decimal digits, a `double` about 15 decimal digits.

The Foundation framework also provides the `NSDecimalNumber` class for doing *base-10 arithmetic*, with a precision of *38 decimal digits*:

```
NSString *val1 = @"355.00";
NSString *val2 = @"55555550.00";
NSDecimalNumber *dec1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:val1];
NSDecimalNumber *dec2 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:val2];
NSDecimalNumber *decsum = [dec1 decimalNumberByAdding:dec2];
NSString *result = [decsum stringValue];
// --> 55555905
```

Answer (score 2):

See: [float vs. double precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision)

Floating point numbers in C use [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) encoding.

This type of encoding uses a sign, a significand, and an exponent.

Because of this encoding, you can never guarantee that you will not have a change in your value.

Also, the number of significant digits can change slightly since it is a binary representation, not a decimal one.

Single precision (float) gives you 23 bits of significand, 8 bits of exponent, and 1 sign bit.

Double precision (double) gives you 52 bits of significand, 11 bits of exponent, and 1 sign bit.