# Why is the intpart output of modf forced to be a double?

Tags: c

Why is the intpart output of modf forced to be a double?  Isn't the output, by definition, going to always be an int, unless the integer part of the input is itself a double.

```
  int main ()
{
  double p, fractpart, intpart;

  fractpart = modf (p , &intpart);

}
```

Comment: What type would you prefer, given that the range can frequently be larger than any integer type you can depend upon having available? C doesn't have dynamic typing (or anything similar) to allow it to decide the return type based on the value.

Comment: Isn't double inherently less precise than int.  So couldn't I output an int which is more precise and should be perfectly suited to handle the output.

Comment: No, `double` is not inherently less precise than `int`. In a typical case, `double` can represent every integer in the range -2e53..2e53 precisely.

Comment: Basically, back when it was defined, many many years ago, there weren't integer types big enough to hold the result.

Comment: assigning a double a value like 10.0 will fail when compared with 10, because floating points and double's can't always exactly represent an integer value (from what I get it has something to do with IEEE). That is what I mean by less precise. So if this is the case then isn't an INT output better if you need that absoluteness.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: For `long double` on some systems, there still aren't. On my system, `long double` can represent integers from -2**64 to +2**64 exactly; `long long` can only represent integers from -2**63 to 2**63-1.

Comment: @Mo1: `10.0` is not a good example; it can be represented exactly by any floating-point type that obeys the model defined in the C standard.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I could argue that you're discussing `modfl()` when you mention `long double`, but I won't.  Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `modf` function breaks a `double` argument into integral and fractional parts; for example, given `3.75` it returns `0.75` and stores `3.0` in the object pointed to by its second argument.

The question is, what should happen if you call it with a value that's too big to fit in any integer type?

If it returned an `int` result, or even a `long long` or `intmax_t` result, it would have to deal with overflow somehow, which would likely require adding an extra parameter to distinguish valid results from overflows.

By returning a `double` result, overflow is not possible; for very large arguments, it can just return the argument value and set the fractional part to `0.0`. It simplifies the function considerably. (If you want to convert the result to an integer you can do so -- but you should check the result against the bounds of the integer type you're using.)

On modern systems `double` is typically 64 bits, and can represent integers up to about 2<sup>53</sup> exactly. If you call `modf` with a value greater than 2<sup>53</sup>, then the `double` value itself can't necessarily hold an exact integer value; having `modf` return even a 64-bit integer wouldn't provide any extra precision.

A `long double`, depending on the implementation, might be able to hold a wider range of exact integer values than even the widest integer type; on such a system, making `modfl` return an integer would lose precision relative to having it return `long double`.

So having `modf` (and `modff` and `modfl`) return an integer rather than a floating-point value would lose range without any corresponding gain in precision.

Comment: Floating point numbers in C use IEEE 754 encoding.
This type of encoding uses a sign, a significand, and an exponent.
Because of this encoding, you can never guarantee that you will not have a change in your value. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision

Comment: Doesn't the IEE 754 encoding mean that a double will be less precise than an int.  Are int's subject to the same variability?

Comment: I guess never mind...this comment seems to address my question.   Under IEEE 754, it's easily guaranteed that there is no change in the values 0.5, 0.046875, or 0.376739501953125 versus their decimal representations. (These are all diadic rationals with numerator fitting in the mantissa and base-2 logarithm of the denominator fitting in the exponent.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision

Comment: @Mo1: C doesn't require IEEE 754. The width of `int` is implementation-defined, and can be as narrow as 16 bits.

Comment: I'm so confused.  So why do floats return results different than an input.  If I float x  = 0.0  and I printf "x", from what I understand, I can get a whole bunch of 0.000101010101010198384929482 garbage.  And that is what make floats unreliable and less precise.  And isn't a double just a big float?  I thought it was because of the encoding.

Comment: int has only 32 bits on most modern systems, and double has 53 bits of mantissa that can represent all numbers in int's range, moreover, int's dynamic range is much smaller than double's

Comment: @Mo1: Floating-point numbers can and often do lose precision; for example a binary floating-point type can't represent `0.1` exactly. But it *can* represent `0.0` exactly, as well as any number within its range and precision that's equal to a whole number multiplied by a power of 2.0. `float x = 0.0;` will set `x` to exactly `0.0`. A `double` is similar to `float`, but with greater range and precision. See David Goldberg's classic article ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Thank you, anonymous user, for the edit. (I had reversed the way `modf` returns the integral and fractional values. It's correct now.)