# Wrong behaviour of atof()

Tags: c, atof

Sample.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{
    char str[10] = "111.1";
    float f = (float)atof(str);
    printf ("\n (%s  ,  %f) \n",str,f);
}
```

Output of above code is :
 (111.1  ,  111.099998)

Please suggest whether i am missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use it with a `double`. I often had some random issues by using `float`

Comment: its because of typecasting from double(return type of `atof`) to float, resulting into closest possible float.

Comment: by default atof returns in double datatype.

Comment: Floats have less precision than doubles.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but 1) you don't need to hardcode the size of an array if you're initializing it, so here `char str[] = "111.1";` would've been enough 2) implicit `int` return type for functions is pretty old C; whatever you're learning from, I suggest you use something newer.

Answer (score 2):

Changing from float to double helps a bit, but doesn't "solve" the "problem." First, there is no problem, just a perception that there is one. As Dayal Rai said, 111.099998 is the closest you can get to 111.1 using a float. But even a double cannot represent 111.1, as you will find if you print its value using more decimal places. See the reference quoted by Sohil Omer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this , as atof returns double , Reference [Man Page of atof()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atof)

```
double f = atof(str);
```

For more info,
[Double vs Float in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision)