# How to get numbers toPrecision higher than 21 in javascript

Tags: javascript, precision

How to get numbers toPrecision higher than 21 in javascript?

I am getting this number 
8.426661309628124e+22

When it should be this 
8.4266613096281243382112

When I use toPrecision(21) I get this
8.42666130962812428616e+22

```js
// my result is a result of this calculation  
 var val=10;
 feb=[0,1];
 for(var i=2; i<=val; i++){
    feb[i]= feb[i-2] + Math.pow(feb[i-1],2);
    }    
    console.log(feb[val-1])
```

Comment: It is implementation dependent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision

Comment: Is there any way around it?

Comment: Try using `.toFixed(22)` instead.  Keep in mind however that 32-bit floats have an accuracy of around [7 significant digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision) (the rest are likely garbage)

Comment: toFixed is between 0 and 20

Comment: Do you have a requirement for this level of precision? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: it is a result from this calculation feb[i]= feb[i-2] + Math.pow(feb[i-1],2); It has nothing to do with my method, but the precision involved.

Comment: @Hunter McMillen if you think I should include it in the question because it might be relevant, let me know. Maybe I require a second algo to extend the precisison.

Comment: If you need an exact number you should look at javascript libraries that implement BigNumber or some such.  Your number is > [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

Comment: Use a [BigInteger library](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js), or another programming language that can deal with large integers, like Python (see this [example script](https://repl.it/H7ck/2)).

Comment: @trincot python is good at handling big numbers but I would prefer a solution in js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the precision of JavaScript's internal representation of numbers ([double-precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)) is limited, you'd need one of the existing Big Integer libraries that overcomes this limitation.

For instance, you could use [`bignumber.js`](http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/):

```js
// Configure to (almost) never use scientific notation:
BigNumber.config({ EXPONENTIAL_AT: 1e+9 });
var val=10;
// Store the feb numbers as BigNumber instances:
feb=[new BigNumber(0), new BigNumber(1)];
for(var i=2; i<=val; i++){
    feb[i] = feb[i-2].plus(feb[i-1].toPower(2));
    console.log(feb[i].toString());
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bignumber.js/4.0.2/bignumber.min.js"></script>
```

Note that some other languages provide big integers automatically, such as Python:

```
val=10
feb=[0,1]
for i in range(2, val+1):
    feb.append(feb[i-2] + feb[i-1] ** 2)
    print(feb[i])
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/H7ck/2).