# Value type preventing calculation?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program for class that simply calculates distance between two coordinate points (x,y).

```
differenceofx1 = x1 - x2;
differenceofy1 = y1 - y2;
squareofx1 = differenceofx1 * differenceofx1;
squareofy1 = differenceofy1 * differenceofy1;
distance1 = sqrt(squareofx1 - squareofy1);
```

When I calculate the distance, it works. However there are some situations such as the result being a square root of a non-square number, or the difference of x1 and x2 / y1 and y2 being negative due to the input order, that it just gives a distance of 0.00000 when the distance is clearly more than 0. I am using double for all the variables, should I use float instead for the negative possibility or does double do the same job? I set the precision to 8 as well but I don't understand why it wouldn't calculate properly?

I am sorry for the simplicity of the question, I am a bit more than a beginner.

Comment: Usually, for distance, it's `distance1 = sqrt(squareofx1 + squareofy1);`

Comment: "or the difference of x1 and x2 / y1 and y2 being negative due to the input order" Doesn't matter, the square will be positive.

Comment: `float` is for single precision floating point values. `double` is for double precision floating point values. Both types are used for floating point values, but `double` have higher precision and can represent larger or smaller numbers.

Comment: why would it give distance as 0 for some situations tho even tho the difference isn't 0?

Comment: Because its `a² + b² = c²`, not `a² - b² = c²`, as @fefe already pointed out.

Comment: And we normally use the `std::hypot()` library function defined in `<cmath>`, which helps avoid overflow and precision problems, rather than reimplementing it with basic arithmetic like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the distance formula wrong
it should be
distance1 = sqrt(squareofx1 + squareofy1);
instead of 
distance1 = sqrt(squareofx1 - squareofy1);
due to the wrong formula if squareofx1 is less than squareofy1 you get an error as  sqrt of a negative number is not possible in case of real coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, your formula is incorrect change it to `distance1 = sqrt(squareofx1 + squareofy1)` as @fefe mentioned. Btw All your calculation can be represented in one line of code:

```
distance1 = sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
```

No need for variables like **differenceofx1**, **differenceofy1**, **squareofx1**, **squareofy1** unless you are using the results stored in these variables again in your program.

**Secondly**, [Double](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) give you more precision than [float](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). If you need precision more than 6-7 places after decimal use Double else float works too. Read more about [Float vs Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision)