# Decimal calculations not accurate

Tags: python, decimal

I am working on a program that needs a high level of accuracy. Unfortunately when I run a simple code such as this:

`65.2805151+66.5374849`

the result is `131.81799999999998`

Instead of a `131.818`

How can I go about addressing this issue?

Comment: what type are you using for your variables? int, float... etc.

Comment: The input value could be either an int or a float - so I am defaulting to float in order to get a more accurate result

Comment: If you need to need high accuracy you should not be using float, but rather double or decimal, take a look at this: http://net-informations.com/q/faq/float.html , tell me if you get it to work :)

Comment: @Stanley I believe Python's floats have double precision

Comment: @Kei Single precision (float) gives you 23 bits of significand, 8 bits of exponent, and 1 sign bit. Double precision (double) gives you 52 bits of significand from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5098598/3712531

Comment: @Stanley the question has the Python tag. According to the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) `There are three distinct numeric types: integers, floating point numbers, and complex numbers. In addition, Booleans are a subtype of integers. Integers have unlimited precision. Floating point numbers are usually implemented using double in C` Python doesn't have a separate type for floats and doubles. What is referred to as a "float" in Python is usually a double.

Comment: @Kei Ahhh, my bad, thanks for giving me a heads up! I will stay on the lookout for that next time. And happy to learn something new, thanks again Kei

Comment: @Stanley. Thank you. Got it to work by converting all the inputs into Decimal.

Comment: @Anubhav That is great!

Answer (score 0):

You can work `mpmath` which is a high precision package. Here's the [link](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/contexts.html#arbitrary-precision-floating-point-mp) to its site

```
import mpmath as mp
a = 65.2805151
b = 66.5374849
mp.dps = 50
summation = [a,b]
print(mp.fsum(summation))
```

Output:

```
131.818
```