# Random digits printed when printing more than 6 decimal digits in float datatype in C (GCC compiler)

Tags: c, gcc, precision

I was executing following C code-

```
float a=3.25678932;
printf("%0.10f\n",a);
```

The above printf() statement giving following output:

```
3.2567892075
```

I am not able to understand how other four digits('2075') are coming after first six digits('256789') after decimal.

Comment: That sounds perfectly normal. Do you know how floating point numbers work in computers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C implementation likely uses the IEEE-754 binary32 format for `float`. In this format, every finite number is, in effect, a sign (+ or −) applied to a 24-bit integer M multiplied by some power of two.

Since 2<sup>1</sup> ≤ 3.25678932 < 2<sup>2</sup>, the power of two used is 2<sup>2−24</sup> = 2<sup>−22</sup>. (The −24 scales the 24-bit integer to between ½ and 1, and the 2 scales that to between 2 and 4.)

Then, to choose the integer M, we choose the integer that is closest to 3.25678932/2<sup>−22</sup>. 3.25678932/2<sup>−22</sup> is about 13,659,964.472, so we use 13,659,964.

Thus, the result of converting 3.25678932 to `float` is 13,659,964•2<sup>−22</sup>, which is exactly 3.25678920745849609375.

When you print this rounded to 10 digits after the decimal point, the result is “3.2567892075”.